# Word deleting tabe column via vba macros gives an error

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to copy data from excel to the word table and then delete some columns from table. I can copy data to table, but when I delete column it gives error:

> Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths.

My code:

```
Public Tbl1 As Table
Sub callExcel()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ismayilov\Desktop\test")

roomNumber = InputBox("Enter the room number to copy word:", "Room Number")
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result = roomNumber
exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=roomNumber
Dim rVis As Range, rData As Range
exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A1:$H600").Copy

Set Tbl1 = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add _
(Range:=Selection.Range, numRows:=1, NumColumns:=8)

Tbl1.Range.Paste
Tbl1.Columns(1).Delete

exWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
Set exWb = Nothing
Set Tbl1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: can you add a screen shot of your excel and/or word (after it's copied) tables...

Comment: How can I upload photo here? Or is it ok upload externaly to put link here?

Comment: Here is photo http://s2.postimg.org/g8ojs8oqh/copied.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
Tbl1.Range.Paste
```

into the following one:

```
tbl1.Range.PasteAppendTable
```

**EDIT** It seems that `.PasteAppendTable` requires some time to be invoked. Therefore try to add this additional section:

```
'...your code

'let's wait a second before pasting (could be cut to 0.5 sec)
Dim tmpStart
tmpStart = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
Loop While (tmpStart + 1) > Timer

tbl1.Range.PasteAppendTable

'...your code
```

Comment: Thank you,it worked :) But all the borders has gone. I should set borders with code I think. Hmm?

Comment: Yes, you could do it with this two lines: `tbl1.Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle` and
`tbl1.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle`

Comment: It worked one time, but now it gives error: command is not available

Comment: that is strange, it seems that `pasteAppendTable` need time to be available... so try this edited code in the answer...

Comment: this waiting procedure solved that problem on my computer... try to increase waiting time from 1 to ... 5-10 sec and check if it solves the problem. Give me feedback next...

Comment: It started woking again :) Sometimes work fine, sometimes does not work. But I dont understand what is the reason of this?

Comment: I think it's a problem of copy-paste procedure which requires some more time here... One additional tip for further problems- try to exit word if problem returns

Comment: When I add new line of code it stops working. I change tbl1.Range.PasteAppendTable code to tbl1.Range.Paste run one time. And after that I again change to tbl1.Range.PasteAppendTable it starts working.  Is there clever way? Because to increase waiting time does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Sleep function might work.

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" _
   (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub Sleep()

Sleep 1000   'Implements a 1 second delay

End Sub
```