# VBA Word 2010 Paste Error / No Wait Command

Tags: vba, wait, ms-word, paste

I have a project that takes several documents as inputs, does some processing on them, and creates several new documents at the end. I am currently running into problems with pasting content from one Word document into another. The following code snippet seemed relevant:

```
Set refOrigin = FindReference(OriginDoc)
Set refDest = PasteDoc.Range(PasteDoc.Content.Start, PasteDoc.Content.End)
refDest.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
refOrigin.Copy
refDest.Paste
```

When running this code, I will *occasionally* get Run-time error 4198, `Command Failed` at the paste line in the code. However, when I go into the debugger, I can see that both refDest and refOrigin are valid ranges. Furthermore, when I step through the code line-by-line, it works. However, I can tell that in the instance where it failed, it inserted an embedded Word document already.

I've done some research on the issues and I believe that there is some type of problem of the code running to fast for the clipboard to keep up with it sometimes. This makes sense to me because when I run the macro from a document on a network drive, it runs without a hitch.

I thought that I would be able to simply add a wait command with `Application.Wait`, but it turns out that Word 2010 doesn't support this command; it's only in Excel.

Does anyone have ideas as to the root of this problem, possible solutions, or any way to give Word 2010 a wait command? Thanks.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443655/word-deleting-tabe-column-via-vba-macros-gives-an-error/16444492#16444492) similar question and the answer which solved the problem...

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, the following code mimics the Excel `Application.Wait' method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443655/word-deleting-tabe-column-via-vba-macros-gives-an-error/16444492#16444492) question.

```
Dim tmpStart
tmpStart = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
Loop While (tmpStart + 1) > Timer
```